# Inovice: PDF draw table for purchased item

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, adminhtml, invoice, pdf

PDF Invoice Design is not proper. Text are not aligned properly.  I just want to make the text aligned properly or draw nice table for it.

```
 app/code/core/mage/sales/model/pdf/abstract.php

 app/code/core/mage/sales/model/pdf/invoice.php
```

i did look in both files.

in `invoice.php` file is function **_drawHeader(Zend_Pdf_Page $page)** that is for the headings.

while the printed items like: product name, price , qty etc are not properly aligned. i want to draw nice table for it.

i did changed            **$this->y -= 10;**  also did try to change the parameter of the array   **$lines**  but not working.

need help to aligned text and draw table in PDF.

find that attachment:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the file `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Items_Invoice_Default` which is in

```
 app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice
```

Comment: what should i change?  i know there is file abstract.php and invoice.php in  app/code/core/mage/sales/model/order/pdf/invoice.php and abstract.php

Comment: check the path there is not the file abstract.php, you need to change in `default.php` in the feed values

Comment: /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf on thios path there is abstract.php file.  i don't see any default.php file there

Comment: path is `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice` check the answer, got to `/Items/Invoice` from your path

Comment: alright.. what should i change there? i want to increase the width of the sku section because there will be big sku name  so i want to increase space for sku section while reduce the space for the price, quntity and tax section..

Comment: change the feed values

Comment: welcome @torris.. don't forget to close this question

Comment: how to close this question?